# MYSQL pivot / turning rows into columns where a value matches

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

I could really use some help on how to pivot a table based on similar values.

```
   day  |  startDate
-----------------------
Monday  |  09:00
Monday  |  13:00
Tuesday |  08:30
Tuesday |  12:30
```

Ideally, I would like my results to be something like...

```
   day  |  firstStartDate | secondStartDate
-------------------------------------------
Monday  |       09:00     |     13:00
Tuesday |       08:30     |     12:30
```

Generally speaking I know that I will always only have two instances for each day, so converting them into columns can be a fixed thing.

Any suggestion would be super appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this could be done using a GROUP BY, like so

```
SELECT 
   day, 
   MIN(startDate) as firstStartDate, 
   MAX(startDate) as secondStartDate 
FROM TableName 
GROUP BY day
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a self join

```
select a.day , a.startDate as firstStartDate, b.startDate as secondStartDate
from my_table as a 
inner join my_table as b  on a.day = b.day and a.startDate < b.startDate
```